# Configuration is not saving after reboot

Tags: configuration

I have

Ubuntu 13.04

13.4 Driver version.

Monitor and TV, both with FullHD resolution.

Monitor on DVI, TV on HDMI.

i use "sudo amdcccle" to configure "extended displays" mode, but after reboot there is no signal on TV, so i must visit "sudo amdcccle" again.

P.S. i can't start CCC withput using terminal, it's just ignores me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start it with gksu amdcccle instead. You should never start graphical applications with sudo, maybe that's the problem.
Also, can't you simply run it as a normal user (without sudo nor gksu)?
Good luck!